# How to get the aspnetdb username in parameter when i'm binding data

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, aspnetdb

I'm wondering how to access the username of the current user login on the site, i want to bind that value in my datalist. I'm using the default ASPNETDB database. When you are doing it in C# code you can just write `

```
User.Identity.Name
```

But how do i access it in ASP code?

Edit: just want to clear up it's for the parameter to the binding i need the username.

Comment: try <%# System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

The embedded code block is used to execute programming statements and call functions in the current page class during the page-rendering phase.

```
<% ... %> embedded code blocks syntax
```

In this instance to show the username put `User.Identity.Name` within a code block on your page like so.

```
<%# System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name %>
```